# Why does my Knockout binding only work intermittently?

Tags: knockout.js

Some of the time, my observable 'searchTerm' does not update. It's bound to an input field. This does not seem to happen if I don't use a special value for valueUpdate.

I have no errors in my console.

```
<div data-bind="visible: true" style="display: none">

                <div class="search" style="clear:both;">
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: searchTerm, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
                </div>

                <!-- ko if: filteredGames().length > 0 -->
                <div data-bind="foreach: filteredGames">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.loadGame">
                        <img data-bind="attr: {src: img}"/>
                        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                        <div class="play-game-btn">Play game</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: filteredGames().length == 0 -->
                    <p>No games found</p>
                <!-- /ko -->

            </div>
```

Here's my viewmodel code:

```
window.games = [{"name": "name1", "url": "http://example.com", "width": 100, "height":100}]; // usually comes from the server

function GamesViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    this.games = window.games;
    this.noGames = ko.observable(false);
    this.searchTerm = ko.observable('');

    // this is to debug the binding itself. it logs something half the time.
    this.searchTerm.subscribe( function( x ) {
        console.log( x );
    });

    this.filteredGames = ko.computed( function() {
        var filter = self.searchTerm().toLowerCase();
        if (!filter) {
            return this.games;
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.games, function (item) {
                return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
            }); 
        }
    });

    this.resetSearch = function() { this.searchTerm(null); };

    this.loadGame = function() {
        window.open( this.url, this.name, "width="+this.width+",height="+this.height );
    }
}

ko.applyBindings( new GamesViewModel() );
```

What might be happening here?

**Further detail**

This happens only after a soft refresh (Cmd-R). Doing a hard refresh (Cmd-Shift-R) makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error in the console when I test yor code:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined;
>   Bindings value: if: filteredGames().length > 0

And when this error occurs, the "searchTerm" property is not updated.

Try changing this code block of your view:

```
<!-- ko if: filteredGames().length > 0 -->
```

To this:

```
<!-- ko if: filteredGames() && filteredGames().length == 0 -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My apologies - the `window.games` variable is set up before that script runs. I will edit the original code to fix this so you can see the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a script conflict.